# How to select from duplicate rows from a table?

Tags: sql-server, select, duplicate-data

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID TINYINT NULL, COL1 CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'A')
INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (2,'B')
INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'A')
INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'B')

INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (1,'B')
INSERT INTO TEST(ID,COL1) VALUES (2,'B')
```

I would like to select duplicate rows from that table. How can I select them?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT TEST.ID,TEST.COL1
FROM TEST WHERE TEST.ID IN
(SELECT ID
FROM TEST WHERE TEST.COL1 IN
(SELECT COL1
FROM TEST WHERE TEST.ID IN
(SELECT ID
FROM TEST
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Where's the error? What do I need to modify?

And I would like it to show as:

```
ID   COL1
---- ----
1    A
1    A
1    B
1    B

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sql Server 2005+ and CTE you could try

```
;WITH Dups AS (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Col1 ORDER BY ID, Col1) Rnum
    FROM @TEST t
)
SELECT *
FROM Dups
WHERE Rnum > 1
```

OR just a standard

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Col1,
        COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM    @TEST
GROUP BY    ID, 
            Col1
HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1
```

**EDIT:**

Display duplicate rows

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    @Test t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID,  
                    Col1, 
                    COUNT(1) Cnt 
            FROM    @TEST 
            GROUP BY    ID,  
                        Col1 
            HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1 
        ) dups  ON  t.ID = dups.ID 
                AND t.Col1 = dups.Col1
```

Comment: I would like to get as following:

ID   COL1
---- ----
1    A
1    A
1    B
1    B

(4 row(s) affected)

Comment: All duplicates row from table. Sorry for my bad English!Please see my comment on bart's Answer.

Comment: Thanks astander. It works . Definitely I got what I want to show! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, col1
FROM Test
GROUP BY id, col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

when you use

```
SELECT id, col1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Test
GROUP BY id, col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

you practically have all duplicate rows and how often they appear. You can't identify them individually either way.

A slower way would be:

```
SELECT id, col1
FROM Test T
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Test I
       WHERE I.id = T.id AND I.col1 = T.col1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Every row in that set of data is a duplicate

```
select id, col1, count(*)
from test
group by id, col1
```

shows this

if you want to exclude the 2,B rows you need to do it explicitly

eg

```
SELECT id, col1
FROM Test
WHERE NOT (id = 2 and col1 = 'B')
```

Comment: The result is just for sample: We may add next 3,C or next 2,B / 4, C.
I want to show all duplicate rows in that table. Sorry I think my question is not clear enough to understand for you all. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TEST t
           INNER JOIN (
                       SELECT ID,COL1 
                       from test 
                       GROUP BY ID,COL1
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                      ) 
                       AS t2 
                       ON t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.COL1 =t.COL1
order by t.ID,t.COL1
```